# Deleting a file in FileSystem API after read is finished?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-filesystem

So I'm stuck trying to figure this out.

```
fileEntry.file(function(file){
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function (e) {
    var anchor = document.createElement("a");
    anchor.setAttribute('href', "data:text/tsv;charset=UTF-8," + encodeURIComponent(this.result));
    anchor.setAttribute("download", "log.tsv");
    anchor.innerHTML = "Download Log Now";
    document.body.appendChild(anchor);

    alert("Download by clicking the damn link at the bottom.");

    //delete the file?
  }

  reader.readAsText(file);
});
```

So my question is how do you delete the file after it's been read? I've tried doing `fileEntry.remove(function(){console.log("File Removed.")});` where the comment is but that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: .remove() accepts an error callback as second parameter. what does the error message say?

Comment: It doesn't say anything. It's like the whole thing doesn't get run at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on promise-based [bro-fs](https://github.com/vitalets/bro-fs) where this is more clean:

```js
fs.init()
  .then(() => fs.readFile('file.txt'))
  .then(content => console.log(content))
  .then(() => fs.unlink('file.txt'))
```